# How to Implement ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: django-models

I am trying to create a small django project of a football application to show the stats & stuff.. to start with I created two classes in my models.py.. with a many to many relation.. but for some reason it's throwing a strange Database Error: **no such table: football_league_team**
please any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Team(models.Model):
        team_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
        team_code = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
        team_home = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
        team_registry_date = models.DateTimeField('Date of Registry')

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.team_name

class League(models.Model):
        league_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        league_code = models.CharField(max_length=4)
        league_division = models.IntegerField()
        team = models.ManyToManyField(Team)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.league_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed the field `football_league_team` in one of your model. Django doesn't know it and is still expecting said field. Depending your Django version, there are several ways to reset the corresponding model.

---

#### Django 1.4 and lower

`> ./manage.py reset <appname>`

I believe it works for earlier versions of Django, not sure though. Keep in mind that this option will reset each models of your application as opposed to the below method which allow single table drops.

#### Django 1.5 and higher

`> ./manage.py sqlclear <appname>`

will print out the commands to clear the database from the application's models.

`> ./manage.py dbshell`

Will allow you to use the *sqlclear* commands in order to drop the tables yopu want to be reseted.

Comment: And Can you please recommend any good books or online sources to learn Django..!!

Comment: Well, I'm not a fan of learning a technology from one big source (even though I found the official documentation to be very efficient for initial reference). I'd rather learn from daily users (like in there) and acquire good practices from that ;]. But if you insist, I took some tutorials from here and there, googling *django tutorials*. Some were bad (only repeating the official ones), other were real good (blog application, registration, and such...). Have fun !

Comment: Feel free to flag as answered if so by the way ;].

Comment: @user2689208 - Do mark this answer as accepted (the green tick next to this answer) if this was useful